# Removing listbox item

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listbox

Im at beginner level and have tried for a while now. Im trying to remove an item from a `ListBox` with the help of a remove button. The code is not giving away any errors but the items is not disappearing from the list.
This is the part im struggling with

```
void taBort()
{
    listboxKontakter.SelectedItems.Remove(listboxKontakter.SelectedItems);
    textboxAnteckningar.Clear();
    textboxGatuadress.Clear();
    textboxNamn.Clear();
    textboxPostnummerOrt.Clear();
    textboxEmail.Clear();
    textboxFödelsedag.Value = DateTime.Now;
}
```

Here is my entire code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace adressboken
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        List<Kontakter> kontaktLista = new List<Kontakter>();
        Kontakter person;
        string path = "kontakter.txt";



        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void LäggTill_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            person = new Kontakter();
            person.FullständigtNamn = textboxNamn.Text;
            person.Gatuadress = textboxGatuadress.Text;
            person.PostnummerOrt = textboxPostnummerOrt.Text;
            person.Födelsedag = textboxFödelsedag.Value;
            person.Email = textboxEmail.Text;
            person.Anteckningar = textboxAnteckningar.Text;

            kontaktLista.Add(person);

            listboxKontakter.DataSource = null;
            listboxKontakter.DisplayMember = "FullständigtNamn";
            listboxKontakter.DataSource = kontaktLista;

            textboxAnteckningar.Clear();
            textboxGatuadress.Clear();
            textboxNamn.Clear();
            textboxPostnummerOrt.Clear();
            textboxEmail.Clear();
            textboxFödelsedag.Value = DateTime.Now;

            textboxAntal.Text = kontaktLista.Count.ToString();
        }

        private void Rensa_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textboxAnteckningar.Clear();
            textboxGatuadress.Clear();
            textboxNamn.Clear();
            textboxPostnummerOrt.Clear();
            textboxEmail.Clear();
            textboxFödelsedag.Value = DateTime.Now;
        }
        void taBort()
        {

            textboxAnteckningar.Clear();
            textboxGatuadress.Clear();
            textboxNamn.Clear();
            textboxPostnummerOrt.Clear();
            textboxEmail.Clear();
            textboxFödelsedag.Value = DateTime.Now;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            kontaktLista = new List<Kontakter>();
            string line = "";
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path);
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] listarray = line.Split(',');
                person = new Kontakter();
                person.FullständigtNamn = listarray[0];
                person.Gatuadress = listarray[1];
                person.PostnummerOrt = listarray[2];
                person.Email = listarray[3];
                person.Födelsedag = Convert.ToDateTime(listarray[4]);
                person.Anteckningar = listarray[5];
                kontaktLista.Add(person);
            }
            sr.Close();
            listboxKontakter.DataSource = kontaktLista;
            listboxKontakter.DisplayMember = "FullständigtNamn";
        }

        public void listboxKontakter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            person = (Kontakter)listboxKontakter.SelectedItem;
            textboxNamn.Text = person.FullständigtNamn;
            textboxGatuadress.Text = person.Gatuadress;
            textboxPostnummerOrt.Text = person.PostnummerOrt;
            textboxEmail.Text = person.Email;
            textboxFödelsedag.Value = person.Födelsedag;
            var selectedindex = listboxKontakter.SelectedItems;
        }

        private void Spara_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path);
            foreach (Kontakter k in kontaktLista)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(k.FullInfo);
            }
            sw.Close();
        }

        private void taBortToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            taBort();
        }

        private void TaBort_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            taBort();
        }


    }


}
```

Comment: oh sorry. Yes its Windows Forms Application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code seems to remove all selected items, and does not refresh.

How about:

```
listboxKontakter.SelectedItems.Remove(listboxKontakter.SelectedItem);
listboxKontakter.Refresh();
```

You remove only the single selected item, then refresh your listbox.

If you want to remove **ALL** items try:

```
listboxKontakter.Items.Clear();
```

If you use a **DataSource** try:

```
listboxKontakter.DataSource = null;
```

If all else fails you could loop through the collection and `RemoveAt`:

```
for(int i=listboxKontakter.Items.Count; i > -1; i--) {
{
    listboxKontakter.Items.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

Based on a bit of chatting, this should work for you:

```
void taBort()
{
    var newList = (List<Kontakter>)listboxKontakter.DataSource;
    var ds = newList.Where(k => k.FullständigtNamn != ((Kontakter)listboxKontakter.SelectedItem).FullständigtNamn).ToList();
    listboxKontakter.DataSource = ds;
    listboxKontakter.DisplayMember = "FullständigtNamn";
    textboxAnteckningar.Clear();
    textboxGatuadress.Clear();
    textboxNamn.Clear();
    textboxPostnummerOrt.Clear();
    textboxEmail.Clear();
    textboxFödelsedag.Value = DateTime.Now;
}
```

If you want to remove several items at once try:

```
var ds = newList.Where(k => !listboxKontakter.SelectedItems.Contains(k.FullständigtNamn)).ToList();
```

Comment: Are you using a datasource to populate your listbox?

Comment: yeah thats correct. This is my Form1.Load partially:
            listboxKontakter.DataSource = kontaktLista;
            listboxKontakter.DisplayMember = "FullständigtNamn";

Comment: Null out your data source, see my edit.  you may need to throw a refresh in there as well.

Comment: Ok so now when i press Remove it removes all the items from the listbox, not just the selected one

Comment: I'm beginning to see the problem now.  You only want to remove ONE item, but its in a datasource.  One moment

Comment: yeah exactly, the list only allow for one selected item at the time anyways so its impossible to remove multiple items :)

Comment: is that data source a list<T> object?

Comment: yeah
            listboxKontakter.DataSource = kontaktLista;
        List<Kontakter> kontaktLista = new List<Kontakter>();

Comment: Ok, i made a few assumptions, but I think my last edit there will give you what you need.  Let me know if you have problems.

Comment: im sorry paqogomez but it still doesnt work :/ , Complex DataBinding accepts as a data source either an IList or an IListSource.

You can see the entire code here:
http://pastebin.com/qmwTRAKe

Comment: Ok.. i forgot a `ToList` on the end of the line.  But my new edits have it down.

Comment: It doesnt work and now when i start debug the list is empty, its not reading from the file anymore and when i try to add new contacts they are not showing up in the list :/

Comment: I added items in the `Form` constructor as an example.  the only stuff you should care about is in the `taBort` method.

Comment: oh sorry about that. Yeah now it delete the items from the listbox but the item is is still in the .txt file but ill try sorting that out my self first :) Big thanks for the help!

Comment: Ya, if you want to remove from the text file, thats a different question entirely. Shouldnt be difficult however.  Just open the file, read the lines, determine if the lines should be removed, write a new file, set the datasource.

Comment: Good explaining! Makes my answer look very bad haha. +1

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
listboxKontakter.Items.Remove(itemthatneedstoberemoved)
```

and

```
listboxKontakter.Items.Clear();
```

(I assume you called the listbox, listboxKontakter?)

:

[Take a look at this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8cabccca-f2b9-40c4-9cf5-89cbcbc06f03/remove-selected-items-from-listbox-when-pressed-delete-button)

Comment: That didnt work either and yes my listbox is called listboxKontakter

Comment: @user2752375 Are you sure you have written it right in the button submit?

Comment: well this is in the "void taBort()" i have contextmenu tool and a "remove" button which call for that method and neither works

Answer (score 1):

.SelectedItems is basically just an array list of what items you have selected, so you will need to access those like this .SelectedItems[0] .SelectedItems[1].

However the above code even with the [0], [1] will only remove them from the selected list not the actual list box.
If you want to remove them from the list box you need to use the .Items.Remove call.

```
while(listboxKontakter.SelectedItems.Count >0)
{
listboxKontakter.Items.Remove(listboxKontakter.SelectedItems[0]);
}
```

**EDIT:**
   If it is a single select listbox all you have to do is

```
listboxKontakter.Items.Remove(listboxKontakter.SelectedItem);
```

Comment: that doesnt work, and the listbox only allows single target to be selected so it cant do multiple. The listbox is filled with content from a textfile that loads thru DataSource

Comment: Then you need to also remove the item from your DataSource as the next time your form reloads it will pull that data back in through the DataSource.